# log_2(x + 1) transformation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to implement the log_2(x + 1) transformation in `ggplot2` but am running into issues.

Here is an MWE

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- rexp(100)
y <- rexp(100)

df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y =  y)) + geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2") 
print(p)
```

However, I'm unsure how to best go about transforming the axes, as well as labelling the axes as log_2{x + 1) and log_2(y + 1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `log2_trans` from `scales` with a function to add 1 like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
x <- rexp(100)
y <- rexp(100)

df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y =  y)) + geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = log2_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) x + 1),
                     labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(.x + 1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log2_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) x + 1),
                     labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(.x + 1)))
print(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I see the addition of "+1" in the axes values, which comes from `math_format()`, but it makes the plot look clunky. Is there an easy way to automatically add 1 to the `x` and `y` values so that the `labels` argument is not needed?